# How do i check if a property of any dict in a list matches any string from another list?

Tags: python, list

How do i check if the `"name"` property of any element in `drink_list` matches any string in a separate list (`str_list`)?

```py
drink_list = [
    {
        "name": "Rum & Coke",
        "ingredients": {
            "rum": 50,
            "coke": 150
        }
    }, {
        "name": "Gin & Tonic",
        "ingredients": {
            "gin": 50,
            "tonic": 150
        }
    }]

str_list = ['Gin & Tonic', 'Daquiri']
```

Comment: Do you just want a simple yes/no answer as to whether any names are the same?  Or do you want to know _which_ names specifically match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    drink_list = [
        {
            "name": "Rum & Coke",
            "ingredients": {
                "rum": 50,
                "coke": 150
            }
        }, {
            "name": "Gin & Tonic",
            "ingredients": {
                "gin": 50,
                "tonic": 150
            }
        }]
    str_list = ['Gin & Tonic', 'Rum & Coke', 'Daquiri']

    // make an empty list
    found_list = []
    
   // iterate over drink_list and check if value is in str_list or not
    for drink in drink_list:
        if drink["name"] in str_list:   
            found_list.append(drink["name"]) // append matched value in found_list
    
    print(found_list) // prints desired output in list
```

**Output:**

> ['Rum & Coke', 'Gin & Tonic']

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a list of all the names, do something like that:

```py
>>> l = []
>>> for i in drink_list:
...   if i['name'] in str_list:
...     l.append(i['name'])
... 
>>> l
['Gin & Tonic']
```

You can also append and keep the whole drink dictionary, if you append `i`:

```py
l.append(i)
```

Can also use a list comprehension:

```py
>>> [i['name'] for i in drink_list if i['name'] in str_list]
['Gin & Tonic']
```